# Xamarin forms click event in code behind does not wait for async confirmation in view model

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms

I have a cancel button on a page that has `Command` bound to this in the `ViewModel`:

```
private async void ExecuteCanceledCommand()
{
    bool confirmResult = await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Cancel",
                "Are you sure you want to cancel?",
                "OK",
                "Cancel");

    if (confirmResult)
    {
        // do stuff in viewmodel
    }
        else return;
    }
}
```

and the `Clicked` property bound to this in the `XAML` code behind:

```
public void OnCanceledConfirmed()
{
    // Do stuff in code behind
}
```

I only want to do stuff in the `OnCanceledConfirmed()` method if the user selects OK from the DisplayAlert modal fired from the `ViewModel`.  Is there a way to do this or trigger this when the ok button is clicked from the code behind?

Comment: Why do you want to invoke `OnCancled` when `OK` is clicked? Create a event-method/handler for the button-object and invoke what you want.

Comment: I updated for clarity's sake.  I want to make some changes in the code behind based on whether the user clicks on 'OK' from the pop in the viewmodel.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by moving the modal confirmation dialog to the code behind instead of the ViewModel.  This allows me to do what I want in the code behind and then I can call the method I want in the ViewModel from there.